# Get latest tweets using Twitter Streaming API

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

How can i get a list containing the latest (e.g. 200) tweets(along with the tweet info) on Twitter? I don't want to search for a specific user or keyword, nor to get the auth user tweets.

If the above scenario is possible, then how could i get the next 200 tweets?

In case it matters, I am using JavaScript and parsing returned JSON object to get the data i need.

Thank you

Comment: your solution is [140dev.com](http://140dev.com)

Comment: thank you but i don't think that it helps. i'm not using php,java etc. just pure JavaScript. I've used codebird-js to query twitter and i need info on how to perform the specific search as requested above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get good source code using  [link](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/) here.

***get_tweets.php***  can be used for getting real time tweets and filling them to your *database*. And using simple database operation you can easily extract last 200 tweets because you already getting their tweet time info inside json object.

***parse_tweets.php*** also can be used for putting them into the database in parsed form.